# itext PDF - Greek letters are not appearing in the resulting PDF document

Tags: java, pdf, character-encoding, itext

I am having hard time trying to generate PDF files containing Greek letters using itextpdf. I am reading the strings from an external source as UTF-8 strings. English letters appear in results but not the Greek ones. Searching for the problem, I think it might be related to the font used. I do not know what ttf file to use if this is the problem.
Here is how am creating the font

```
 BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.createFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA,"UTF-8", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
 Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.BOLD);
```

any help is heartily appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a font that has Greek characters in it.
You may find Greek unicode fonts [here](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/Fonts_Greek.html).

You can check an example [here](http://1t3xt.info/examples/browse/?page=example&id=282) on using unicode fonts from the author of itext.

Comment: the example you pointed to is extremely helpful. I ended up using arialuni.ttl and it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Yiannis Gkoufas : var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(UnicodeFontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Comment: Or, if the above doesn't work fine try this for Greek:
var bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(UnicodeFontPath, "CP1253", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem could lead to the way you create the font. Instead of passing "UTF-8" as codepage try to use "CP1253".

```
BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.createFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA,"CP1253", BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
Font times = new Font(bfTimes, 12, Font.BOLD);
```

Btw, BaseFont has static string constnts for CP1250, CP1252 and CP1257...

Answer (score 0):

I used this code:

```
BaseFont fonty = BaseFont.createFont("assets/ARIALBD.TTF", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,       BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
     fonty.setSubset(true);
     Phrase myName = new Phrase("Your Not Latin Words", new Font(fonty,12));
     ColumnText.showTextAligned(canvas,
             Element.ALIGN_LEFT, myName, 66, 400, 0);
```

i had to paste the ARIALBD.TTF to assets folder