# How to recognise greek in HTML Header/Footer itext java

Tags: java, itext

i would like to know how to overcome the problem of the non-recognizable greek characters when XMLWorkerHelper kicks in.

NOTE:
I had the same problem when parsing in the pdf and overcame it with this code (I hope this helps others having the same trouble):

```
p.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream((
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><meta content='text/html; ' http-equiv='content-type'></meta><body style='font-family:calibri;>"+ "<i><b><div >Καλημέρα</div> </b></i><br />" + </body></html>).getBytes()));
```

the above is explained by examples found in the official itext page here:
http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/xml-worker-examples

Problem:

```
public static final FOOTER = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><meta content='text/html; charset=utf-8;' http-equiv='content-type'></meta><body style='font-family:calibri;>greek word alert: Καλημέρα</body></html>";


    public class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper 
    {           
        protected ElementList footer;
        public HeaderFooter() throws IOException, BadElementException {

            footer = XMLWorkerHelper.parseToElementList(FOOTER, null);                  
        }
```

so the above code ends up creating the promised element list but wont type the greek letters on the pdf footer.

The above code is based on the official itext page here: http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-html-headers-and-footers-page

Comment: Hi, it could be irrelevant but your body tag is not well formated: `<body style='font-family:calibri;>`, it misses the closing single quote (') after ";"
Plus this link can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858423/itext-pdf-greek-letters-are-not-appearing-in-the-resulting-pdf-document

Comment: thanks for the answer @elefasGR. Its a mistake of copy - paste, good eyes. (in my code it closes normaly)

The link you have provided is using baseFont which i have avoided to use. Instead I am using css and the font-family calibri on the html tags.
I had the same problem with the fellah on the link though, I overcame it when installed calibri for greek characters on my machine.

Comment: Try to set IDENTITY_H property to your css/style in your header/footer. I am not very sure how to do this though. You can search for @font-face and Identity_h

Comment: I did search around and tried some stuff but did not make it work. Ended up using normal text for the footer. Thanks a lot for the answers @elefasGR