# java: translating string to greek characters

Tags: java, character-encoding, itext

TD:DR, jump to EDIT5.

I'm trying to writte some Greek text into a pdf form via iText. I'm retrieving the string from the DB, where is in Greek, but when I try to print it into the pdf form, it shows nothing (the pdf is also Greek-written). I've tried almost everything I've found, same in here, same in iText forum.

As you can see, the string is in greek:

[image: as you can see, the string is in greek]

but it is not written into the pdf:

[image: but it is not written into the pdf]

EDIT:

I've lost count how the efforts trying to make this happen. Converting the string to an array of bytes and then coding it back was one of the closest aproches i could make. Sadly, there is no much code to be shown. As told befor, i've got an string qich has the dfata shown and when traying to printi it into dthe pdf form with a sentence like `form.getField("municipality").setValue(municipio);`
 the output is, again, the shown.

EDIT2:

Using itext 7.0.4, now we can't create the font, as nor baseforn nor font classes are beeing recogniced as itext classes.

```
import com.itextpdf.*;
...

final String f = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";
Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
...
form.getField("municipality").setValue(municipio);
```

EDIT3:

After inserting the following maven dependency, now I can use de basefonts classes:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.10</version>
</dependency>


float fontSize = (float) 10.0;  
PdfFont font = null;
final String f = (String) VarGlobales.getHTTPApplication().get("ruta.fuentes") + "/FreeSans.ttf";  
    try {
        font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(f, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
PdfReader pdfReader = null;
try {
    pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(
            (String) VarGlobales.getHTTPApplication().get("ruta.tenderForms") + "/" + tenderFormFile));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();           
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(baos);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);
form.getField("municipality").setValue(municipio, font, fontSize);
```

But the string is, once more, not beeing painted. Am I using it correctly?

FYI, the fields created in the pdf form were created via Adobe Acrobat 9.

EDIT4:

Ok, so now it's only iText7

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext7-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
  </dependency>             
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>forms</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>layout</artifactId>
    <version>7.1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>typography</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

And the way im creating the font and traying to change it

```
final String rutaFuente = (String) VarGlobales.getHTTPApplication().get("ruta.fuentes") + "/FreeSans.ttf";  
try {
    font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(rutaFuente, "Cp1250", true);
    normalFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}       
    PdfReader pdfReader = null;
    try {
    pdfReader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream((String)VarGlobales.getHTTPApplication().get("ruta.tenderForms") + "/" + tenderFormFile));
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();           
PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(baos);
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReader, pdfWriter);
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDoc, true);   
form.getField("district").setFont(normalFont);      
form.getField("district").setValue(distrito);
```

Sitll no result is printed.

EDIT5 - TL:DR:

Finally, I did it! Jus wanto to thank the help provided by everyone in this process.

I'm not sure where the problem was, there were probably times when it was impossible to solve my initial problem. Right now it is solved in the following way:

```
normalFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
...
form.getField("district").setFont(normalFont);          
form.getField("district").setValue(distrito);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858423/itext-pdf-greek-letters-are-not-appearing-in-the-resulting-pdf-document

Comment: @fantaghirocco butI'm not using any custom font and theoretically it is not mandatory if using the default for iText, or am I wrong?

Comment: I'm not an iText expert but seems that using a [font that has Greek characters in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3858690) - either custom or not - could solve your issue

Comment: I'll give it a try tomorrow morning, ty!

Comment: Please share your pivotal code and a sample PDF form to reproduce the issue.

Comment: It is unclear whether you are using the recent iText 7, a recent maintenance of the old iText 5, the old iText 5, or an even older version of iText. Please be aware that you should always use the latest version (in this case iText 7.1.2). Also: there is no support for Greek in the default fonts. There is a font called symbol with Greek characters, but those are meant as symbols for mathematical equations. If you want support for the Greek language, you have to provide a font.

Comment: Hi! we are using the 7.0.4 version of iText. Following the tutorials provided, i'm stuck at the point where I'm suppoused to create the font itself. The point is that nor Font nor BaseFont are beein recogniced as itext clasees.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie
In our maven pom.xml dependencies, the ones related to itext are:

kernel version7.0.4
forms version 7.0.4
layout version 7.0.4

Comment: You are using iText 5 code in an iText 7 project. You shouldn't mix both! It is normal that you don't find `BaseFont` in iText 7, because that class was replaced. Please throw away all your code first. Then make a decision: do you want to use iText 5 or iText 7? (iText 7 is recommended.) If you use iText 7, *do not use iText 5 code!!!*

Comment: @BrunoLowagie That's what I was prettending to do, but couldn't find nor any example nor documentation on how to use it whith a form field made on another software, not to mention the maven dependencyes to achive this...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Please, take a look at the fourth edit. Is it possible that it's not working becaus i have no license key added? In your oppinion, should this aproach work? TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I did it! Jus wanto to thank the help provided by everyone in this process.

I'm not sure where the problem was, there were probably times when it was impossible to solve my initial problem. Right now it is solved in the following way:

```
normalFont = PdfFontFactory.createFont("C:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arial.ttf", PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
...
form.getField("district").setFont(normalFont);          
form.getField("district").setValue(distrito);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enconding of non-ASCII symbols is font-dependent. You should look for a font that supports Greek symbols. If you use one of the main fonts in IText, you won't have any trouble; if not, you should **embed** the font as described in the IText manual.

Ps: you should put your code, efforts and version used.

Comment: But are you sure this font support the Greek symbols?

Comment: we a re using the default one. Maeby it is not supported? could you point me to the direction of changing the font?

Answer (score 0):

Well, When all else fails you can convert your Greek String into unicode sequence and send it as such. Then you will know for sure that you are sending String of Greek characters and if the problem persists it is with the ability to correctly display it rather then the content. I wrote an Open Source java library called MgntUtils that has the utilty that converts any String to unicode sequence and vise-versa. All you will have to do is:

```
String codes = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello world");
```

And it will return String `"\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064"`

The same would work for any String in any language including special characters. Here is the link to the article [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) that explains about the library and where to get it (available both on [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.michaelgantman%7CMgntUtils%7C1.5.0.2%7Cjar) and [github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt). In the article search for paragraph: **"String Unicode converter"**

Comment: @MichaelGantamn

Thanks a lot for the effort taken on creating such a great library! After using it, I can tell youy that the main problem is that itext's font can't print the desired characters.

Comment: @Alfredo Piris - You made my day! Thanks for the feedback. Could I ask you for a small favor - could you go to the article that I provided in my answer and write a comment with your feedback? I am trying to advertise my library as I think it is worth it

Comment: @MichaelGantamn Done! Have you got any clue on how to change the font of a form field in itext?
TY!

Comment: @Alfredo Piris - Thanks for the comment. As to your question I worked with iText last time  about 12 - 13 years ago. I was very impressed with the library then but today I certainly would not be able to help you much on practical questions